# Ruby - Retrieve a value from URL params

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm completely new to this so you'll have to excuse my ignorance but I'm trying to pass a dynamic value into a function that gets the sum of all prime numbers up to a limit. I'm passing the dynamic limit through in the URL params but can't seem to make it work:

index.erb:

```
<form action="/primes">
  <input type="text" name="prime_limit" value="<%= @limit %>">
  <input type="submit" value="Get Primes">
</form>
```

app.rb:

```
get '/primes' do
  # TODO - Can we make this dynamic?
    limit = uri.params['prime_limit']

  # TODO - add your prime number solution in the primes.rb file.
  @sum = Primes.sum_to(limit)

  erb :primes, :layout => :main
end
```

primes.rb:

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'

uri = URI.parse(@object.location)
uri_params = CGI.parse(uri.query)

class Primes
  def self.sum_to(limit)
    # TODO - add your prime number solution here...
      require 'prime'
      Prime.each(limit).inject(:+)
  end
end
```

primes.erb:

```
<h1>Prime Numbers</h1>

Sum : <%= @sum %>

<div>
  <a href="/">Back</a>
</div>
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It does not look like rails. Is it sinatra?

Comment: So sorry, yes it's Sinatra. That's the level you're dealing with here!

Comment: Sinatra automatically parses the URL parameters into the `params` hash. You don't need to parse it on your own. Just access `params['prime_limit']`. This is covered in the first section of the Sinatra README, Routes: http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes

Comment: Ok Jordan but where do I call it? I tried adding:

`get '/:prime_limit' do
    limit = params['prime_limit']
end`

To the top of the primes.rb file and weirdly that replaced everything on the page with just the word 'primes'.

I tried changing the app.rb part to:

`limit = params['prime_limit']`

But I got an error:

undefined method `join' for #<String:0x007ff233cc9e58>

Comment: Can you try putting the value of params["prime_limit"]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this example can help you? Just a minimal code that (I think) does what you want sinatra to do.. you get the idea

```
# app.rb
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
    erb :index
end

get '/primes' do
    @sum = Primes.sum_to(params[:prime_limit].to_i)
    erb :primes
end

class Primes
  def self.sum_to(limit)
    # TODO - add your prime number solution here...
    require 'prime'
    Prime.each(limit).inject(:+)
  end
end
```

The `params[]` hash stores querystring and form data. So when you throw a GET request with querystrings that looks like `example.com/app/?arg=3`, `params[:arg]` is set to `3`.

You could also do `get '/app/:arg' do` in sinatra, which makes `/app/45` store `params[:arg] = 45`. Sinatra is a simple but powerful tool, and the documentations are not that long. I think it's worth looking through all or most of them.

Comment: Oh you are my favourite person right now! Thanks so much, it worked perfectly. I will definitely read through the Sinatra documentation, I just got given this challenge from a coding school I'm applying for and I have no experience at all with Sinatra, not even the basics. Thanks again, really appreciate it!